# Sharepoint2010 custom design as WSP

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-branding

I am trying to get a solution for my issue.   I have a set of HTML CSS and Images, which I want to apply to my sharepoint portal as a part of branding.

My concern is I want to make my design as WSP or any other kind of solution so that it can be installed in any sharepoint 2010 portal so that the user can switch back between actual sharepoint design and this custom  design.

In short I have a custom HTML design which I need to implement to any sharepoint website, this design can be turned On or Off by the administrator just using the portal/Site screens.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint branding is always a tricky job. The safest way to achieve your goal is to create a separate masterpage with your new branding. So the user can choose to apply the default branding with the default masterpage and when he wants another branding your customized masterpage can be used.

Create a new SharePoint project and add the needed css inside a mapped layouts folder. Then you can reference your own css file in the new masterpage. Watch out with changing the masterpage, because it contains a lot of placeholders which will render different parts of the page. Try to work around these placeholders and make sure the masterpage works in different scenario's (ex. that the layout isn't broken when page is in edit mode, ...)

Once you are finished with the design, the user can use it by applying it in the settings. Another option to make it easier for the enduser, is to create a control that is a switch to apply your masterpage (ex. with custom action).